# Xacro Error: NoneType object has no attribute getitem

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert my `tortoisebot.urdf.xacro` file to a `tortoisebot.urdf` file by running `rosrun xacro xacro tortoisebot.urdf.xacro > tortoisebot.urdf` When I run this command I get this error:

```
~/tortoisebot_ws/src/tortoisebot_description/robots$ rosrun xacro xacro tortoisebot.urdf.xacro > tortoisebot.urdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/xacro/xacro", line 55, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 696, in main
    eval_self_contained(doc)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 626, in eval_self_contained
    eval_all(doc.documentElement, macros, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 553, in eval_all
    eval_all(body, macros, scoped)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 609, in eval_all
    result = eval_text(at[1], symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 483, in eval_text
    results.append(handle_expr(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 470, in handle_expr
    return eval_expr(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 444, in eval_expr
    result = eval_term(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 418, in eval_term
    result = eval_factor(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 402, in eval_factor
    result = eval_expr(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 439, in eval_expr
    if lex.peek()[0] == lex.OP:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here is my Xacro file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="tortoisebot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" >
    <xacro:property name="pi" value="3.14159265" />
    <xacro:property name="body_radius" value="0.17" />
    <xacro:property name="body_height" value="0.2" />
    <xacro:property name="body_mass" value="2.0" />

    <xacro:property name="rear_caster_radius" value="0.01" />
    <xacro:property name="rear_caster_mass" value="0.1" />

    <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.036" />
    <xacro:property name="wheel_height" value="0.025" />
    <xacro:property name="wheel_mass" value="0.1" />

    <xacro:property name="right_wheel_color" value="${red}" />
    <xacro:property name="left_wheel_color" value="${white}" />
    
    <xacro:macro name="inertia_cylinder" params="mass radius height">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="${mass}"/>
            <inertia ixx="${(${mass} / 12)*((3 * ${radius} * ${radius}) + (${height} * ${height}))}"
                ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${(${mass} / 12)*((3 * ${radius} * ${radius}) + (${height} * ${height}))}"
                iyz="0.0" izz="${(${mass} * ${radius} * ${radius}) / 2}"/>
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>

    <xacro:macro name="inertia_sphere" params="mass radius">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="${mass}"/>
            <inertia ixx="${2 * ${mass} * ${radius} * ${radius} / 5}"
                ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${2 * ${mass} * ${radius} * ${radius} / 5}"
                iyz="0.0" izz="${2 * ${mass} * ${radius} * ${radius} / 5}"/>
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>

    <xacro:property name="white">
        <material name="white">
            <color rgba="1, 1, 1, 1"/>
        </material>
    </xacro:property>

    <xacro:property name="green">
        <material name="green">
            <color rgba="0.05 0.75 0.05 1"/>
        </material>
    </xacro:property>

    <xacro:property name="black">
        <material name="black">
            <color rgba="1, 1, 1, 1"/>
        </material>
    </xacro:property>

    <xacro:property name="red">
        <material name="red">
            <color rgba="0.75, 0.05, 0.05, 1"/>
        </material>
    </xacro:property>

    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${body_height}" radius="${body_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${body_height}" radius="${body_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        
        <xacro:inertia_cylinder mass="${body_mass}" radius="${body_radius}" height="${body_height}" />
        
    </link>

    <link name="rear_caster">
        <visual>
            <geometry>  
                <sphere radius="${rear_caster_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
            
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${rear_caster_radius}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        
        <xacro:inertia_sphere mass="${rear_caster_mass}" radius="${rear_caster_radius}" />
        
    </link>

    <joint name="rear_caster_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="rear_caster"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.1 0 -0.1"/>
    </joint>
    <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="prefix reflect">
        <link name="${prefix}_wheel">
            <visual>
                <geometry>  
                    <cylinder length="${wheel_height}" radius="${wheel_radius}"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="${${prefix}_wheel_color}"/>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder length="${wheel_height}" radius="${wheel_radius}"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>

            <xacro:inertia_cylinder mass="${wheel_mass}" radius="${wheel_radius}" height="${wheel_height}" />
        </link>

        <joint name="${prefix}_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
            <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
            <parent link="base_link"/>
            <child link="${prefix}_wheel"/>

            <origin rpy="${${pi} / 2 * -1} 0 0" xyz="0 ${${reflect} * 0.1175} -0.074"/>
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>
    <xacro:wheel prefix="right" reflect="-1" />
    <xacro:wheel prefix="left" reflect="1" />

</robot>
```

{Update}
I removed the portion from my Xacro file above that I'm pretty sure was SDF, so now the entire file should be only URDF/Xacro. I tried rerunning it, but I got the same error as above.

All help is appreciated!
Thanks,
L

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262633/xacro-error:-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-getitem/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2017-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-27**:\

> When I run this command I get this error: I couldn't get it to format correctly

for error text, console copy-pastes, code and urdf/xacros: please use the *Preformatted Text* button. It's the one with `101010` on it.

Could you please move the contents of the gists to your question body? Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-27**:
A quick look at your `xacro` shows that you are trying to mix `urdf` and `sdf`. That is not supported. I wouldn't be surprised if that is the cause of your error.

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2017-05-27**:
I've updated my question with the code inserted. Thanks for your input on `sdf` I removed the section of the file that I think was SDF and tried rerunning the code with the same error. Any idea as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Xacro evaluates everything that is inside `${}` so the variables inside an expression will be evaluated automatically. As a result xacro doesn't support nested `${}`.

For example:
this fails:
`<origin rpy="${${pi} / 2 * -1} 0 0" xyz="0 ${${reflect} * 0.1175} -0.074"/>`

but this succeeds with the expected result:
`<origin rpy="${pi / 2 * -1} 0 0" xyz="0 ${reflect * 0.1175} -0.074"/>`

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2017-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2017-05-27**:
Thanks that fixed the issue!